# Apache: Mod_Ruid2 - 403 Forbidden

Tags: apache-2.4

Ubuntu + Debian / Apache 2.4

I've been trying to get **mod_ruid2** working for quite some time. I think something is wrong with my basic configuration.

[mod_ruid2 documentation](https://github.com/mind04/mod-ruid2)

To confirm, before installed mod_ruid2 and updating vHosts, everything works fine.

I installed mod_ruid2 via apt and configured a vHost to use ruid as seen below

apachectl confirms ruid2 is loaded. Passes configtest after updating vHost with ruid syntax too.

Created user and group 'cb' via useradd cb -M to use as the vHost user.

Here is the vHost

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName cb.xxx.xx
    DocumentRoot /var/www/cb.xxx.xx/public_html/
    RDocumentChRoot /var/www /cb.xxx.xx/public_html
    RUidGid cb cb

    <Directory "/var/www/cb.xxx.xx/public_html/">
            Require all granted
            RMode config
            RUidGid cb cb
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

And at this point the vHost advises 403 forbidden. The directory was previously owned by www-data - so I ran the following -

```
chown -R cb:cb /var/www/cb.xxx.xx/public_html/
```

I get the same issue. The Apache log at debug levels shows the following each time I hit cb.xxx.xx - nothing else

```
[authz_core:error] [pid 3736] [client 31.53.4.77:63626] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /cb.xxx.xx/public_html/
```

Researching the AH01630 error leads to most others not having 'Require all granted' in their vHost, I do and a grep of the Apache dir ensured all other vHosts have this too.

I replicated the same fault on a Debian server and got the same problem. I believe this is something wrong with my config of mod_ruid2 in the vHost. Specifically I believe its the ChRoot I have incorrect.

```
RDocumentChrRoot - Set chroot directory and the document root inside
RDocumentChRoot          /home /example.com/public_html
```

Documentation on this seems to be very limited, and I'm finding sparse other people with a similar issue. Can anyone share some thoughts please?

It's often used in cPanel/DirectAdmin multi-tenant scenarios - I'd be grateful if you had a working config you could look at

Comment: Wild guess would be that `RDocumentChRoot` changes the path before Apache checks for authorization, and your `<Directory>` should be `/cb.xxx.xx/public_html/` since `/var/www` is outside the chroot.

Comment: You know that feeling when you've spent a very long time looking everywhere other than whats right in front of you.. Thank you, DerkF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the path given in the error message

```
client denied by server configuration: /cb.xxx.xx/public_html/
```

it appears that `RDocumentChRoot` chroot's the request before Apache checks the Directory permissions.  Thus, the path given to `<Directory>` should be the path inside the chroot, or

```
<Directory "/cb.xxx.xx/public_html/">
        Require all granted
        RMode config
        RUidGid cb cb
</Directory>
```